# NextAuth Provider component

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-auth

In the official documentation of NextAuth, they say to wrap the component with the Provider in this way:

```
`
 import { Provider } from "next-auth/client"

 export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
 return (
    <Provider session={pageProps.session}>
       < Component {...pageProps} />
    </Provider>
   )
 }`
```

Is there any problem if I wrap also the Layout and the Head in this way ?

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
 // Use the layout defined at the page level, if avaiable (in my case for the QeAs)
 const getQeAsLayout = Component.getQeAsLayout || ((page) => page);
 return (
    <Provider session={pageProps.session}>
     <Head>
       <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />
     </Head>

     <ThemeProvider theme={brandTheme}>
       <Layout>{getQeAsLayout(<Component {...pageProps} />)}</Layout>
     </ThemeProvider>
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

Please don't consider the line about getQeAsLayout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is not any problem with that.
Session Provider should work properly.

Every child in `Provider` component should have access to `session`.
Provider use React Context under the hood as mentioned in [docs](https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/client#sessionprovider).
Look at [React Context Provider](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#contextprovider) for more info.